# How do I work out how many people would be selected in a specific age range by chance?

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling

I have sampled individuals from 100 centres, all aged 5 to 7 years (a total of 1950 individuals). There were two groups that were sampled separately, at a higher rate:

- those aged 5 years and 11 months to 6 years and 1 month
- those who are within the first three weeks of starting at the centre

I need to work out how many would have been sampled into these groups by chance, if they hadn't been sampled separately at a higher rate than the rest of the individuals.

I wondered if I could use the rest of the sample to do this: look at how many individuals fall into other two month or three week periods, and take an average over the periods?

Another option would be simulation. I'm not sure which would be the best approach, or how to start with either.

Are than any suggestions for approach, and how to get started with the suggested approach?

Comment: The averaging option seems to be reasonable but it may gloss over possible temporal elements (not all months have the same birth rates, major world events can affect birth rates etc). A better option would be to find information regarding birthrates for the specific time period that you are looking at (and as local as you can be while including your whole population) and then weight your sample so that your oversampled group contributes only as much as the true birthrates dictate.